# Why is a second pointer to an Object not set to NULL but the Object pointer?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, object, delete-operator

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Object{};

class Connection
{
  public:
    Connection(Object * _obj);
    Object * obj;
    void status();
};

Connection::Connection(Object * _obj)
{
  obj = _obj;
}

void Connection::status()
{
  cout << obj << endl;
}


int main() {
  Object * myObj = new Object();

  Connection * myConn = new Connection(myObj);

  delete myObj;
  myObj = NULL;

  cout << myObj << endl;
  myConn->status();
  /*
  Output is:

  0
  0x25ec010

  but should be:

  0
  0

  */
}
```

I thought I am only working with pointers in this example. So I don't understand why the pointer in "myConn" is not set to NULL too, because there are two pointers which point to the same address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be 0 because you are copying pointer value. Try using references (&) instead.

Maybe this is not a best example, and `boost::shared_ptr` will be better solution, but this code will work:

```
 // skipped...
 class Connection
 {
 public:
   Connection(Object **_obj);
   Object **obj;
   void status();
 };

 Connection::Connection(Object **_obj) : obj(_obj) { }
 void Connection::status() { cout << *obj << endl; }

 int main()
 {
   Object * myObj = new Object();
   Connection * myConn = new Connection(&myObj);
 // skipped
```

Comment: Maybe this is not a best example, and boost::shared_ptr will be better solution, but this code will work:
// skipped...
class Connection
{
  public:
    Connection(Object **_obj);
    Object **obj;
    void status();
};
Connection::Connection(Object **_obj) : obj(_obj)
{
}
void Connection::status()
{
  cout << *obj << endl;
}

int main() {
  Object * myObj = new Object();

  Connection * myConn = new Connection(&myObj);
// skipped

Comment: @Dmitry M Its better to put code and improvements like this in as an edit to your answer. That way it makes it more complete and it gets formatted properly too. I've added it for you, but feel free to edit if you think it could be done more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

`*myConn` made a **copy** of your `myObj` pointer (when you said `obj = _obj;`). The copy didn't get set to null. (But it's still pointing to a now invalidated address, so don't dereference it!)

Comment: How about a proper deep copy, along with the necessary constructors and assignment operators? No idea what you're trying to achieve, but since you're freely handing heap-allocated memory around, I'm sure that your current design can't be any good.

Comment: the myConn should know if the Object which was provided by the initializer is already deleted. So if yes, then myConn should behave in another way

Comment: @Ben: You need to think about memory management a bit. I'd wager a beer that you could solve all your problems with `std::shared_ptr`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Connection::obj doesnt point to myObj, it points to the value that myObj held. So if you want to fix it you have to manually set the value to null in a function. Or make a second pointer that holds a pointer to a obj, and check if that one is null but would be over complicating it.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is a separate entity from the object it points to.

Several pointers pointing to the same object have no relation with each other (other than the fact that they point to the same object), so they have to be managed separately.

This fact causes a problem in the code example you posted : after deleting the object using the `myObj` pointer, you correctly set the pointer to `NULL` to indicate that it no longer points to a valid object. However, the `myConn->obj` pointer still points to the already deleted object (ie. the pointer is no longer valid).

The use of a shared pointer ([boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)) can help in this kind of situation.

Comment: I disagree with the setting pointers to NULL after deleting (though it is useful in C). It may seem logical but this habit usually hides other potential problems. After a pointer is freed the pointer should be made useless by letting it go out of scope (not by setting it to NULL).

Comment: @Martin : I find it's useful for catching problems early nevertheless, because dereferencing a NULL pointer (due to a mistake in the code eg.) would have a more visible effect (segmentation fault eg.) than dereferencing a pointer that previously pointed to valid memory (you might not even realize that it happened until further down the road).

Comment: De-referencing a NULL pointer is UB. This does not mean you will get a segmentation fault. I find that you actually catch more problems (in debug) by not setting it to NULL as the debug implementations of the dynamic memory manager will usually catch things like a double delete (that you are hiding by setting the member to NULL).

Comment: @Martin : I did not say that you were guaranteed to get a segmentation fault - I gave it as an example of what you might get. In any case, whether or not it's good practice to set a pointer to `NULL` after a `delete` doesn't seem very relevant wrt the question. If ben wanted `myObj` to be `NULL` after the `delete` (so the `cout << myObj << endl;` line would show 0), then setting it to `NULL` was the correct thing to do - and that's all I said ;)